# Order data in a single object without it being IEnumerable

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, sorting, ienumerable

I have a single object. One of the fields within the object is a list of stats. I'm trying to order by one of the fields within the stats. So I have a server, server has a name, worker count, and worker stats... Worker stats has a list of multiple stats like, DA, Server, Client... I want to order those Worker stats by client but still leave the entire object as one Server. I'm trying to do it like this.

`SvcProxy.Server refreshedServer = SvcProxy.GetServer(serverName);
 var tempServer = refreshedServer.WorkerStats.OrderBy(ws => ws.Client);`

But when I do this, tempServer is turned into an Ordered IEnumerable. When I want to leave it as an SvcProxy.Server except with the stats within, ordered by the clients. Is this possible?

There's sensitive data where idk if I could get legally in trouble so I'll post what I can about the class. WorkerStats is an IEnumerable.

```
public IEnumerable<WorkerStatsDisplay> WorkerStats 
{
    get {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(ServerName) || !Active)
        {
            return Enumerable.Empty<WorkerStatsDisplay>();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you want to mutate your class.  That depends on the class.

Comment: Maybe just `refreshedServer.WorkerStats = refreshedServer.WorkerStats.OrderBy(ws => ws.Client).ToList();` ? Depending on what type of collection WorkerStats is.

Comment: `refreshedServer.WorkerStats = refreshedServer.WorkerStats.OrderBy(ws => ws.Client).ToList();` Is saying that it's read only so I would have to mess with something pretty deep that I'm only service referencing.

Comment: Your question isn't clear do you just want to order the list that belongs to your server?

refreshServer.WorkerStats = refreshServer.WorkerStats.OrderBy(ws => ws.Client);

Comment: `tempServer` is named wrong or you don't understand how this works at all. Why do you think the return from `OrderBy()` would be a `Server`?

Comment: What's the type of `WorkerStats`? Is it a field? Property? Readonly? Getter/Setter? Post the class definitions so we can help you.

Comment: @NetMage Not sure I follow about incorrect naming of `tempServer`. I'm just trying to order stats within an object without changing the object. I'm asking if it's possible because I don't know what to think. Anything helpful is appreciated.

Comment: @DanielJackson if the collection is read-only then there isn't much you can do. As the name suggests you can only read the collection. All the linq operates return a new instance of the collection they do not change the collection they are called it. It's a major feature of linq

Comment: WorkerStats only has a get you cannot write to it. Can you change the code in your Server class?

Comment: @Dave I figured I couldn't edit the original. Can I read, order and store a new one in tempServer?

Comment: @Dave Unfortunately I can't edit the Server class. It's a company wide thing that I don't have permission to change.

Comment: @DanielJackson You can create temporary collection of Server Stats. Which is pretty much what you are doing already (just with a variable name that doesn't make sense). You could create a new Server object but remember you cannot write to the ServerStats property (when it's just a get it's effectively just a method) so this won't help. In short you cannot change the ServerStats property of a server from any code really at least from what I can tell from what you've shown us

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158454/discussion-between-dave-and-daniel-jackson).

Comment: Ok @Dave I appreciate the help. I may have to create my own ViewModel class that I can use for my purpose instead of using the original. I appreciate the info. Sounds like that's an answer. It's not possible to do what I'm wanting with the way things are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is use extension methods:

```
public static class ServerExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<WorkerStatsDisplay> GetSortedWorkerStats(this Server server)
    {
        return server.WorkerStats.OrderBy(ws => ws.Client);
    }
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
SvcProxy.Server refreshedServer = SvcProxy.GetServer(serverName);
var ordered = refreshedServer.GetSortedWorkerStats();
```

Make sure to wrap this guy in the same namespace as the original class. You don't have to, but it's SOP and it makes it easier as your extension method is imported by virtue of using the class (since it will live in the same namespace).

While it amounts to the same thing you are doing now, it makes it reusable and available to everyone without having to modify the original class.

I whipped this out real quick. Please check the code for consistency.

Good luck!

Comment: They don't even to store it in a variable if they dont want to, they can just call it when they need it (obviously depends on how often they need it, call once use many times comes to mind)

Comment: That's right, @Dave. I figured I would present it like this to avoid confusion!

Comment: Wow thank you. Very helpful for you to have whipped this up. Much appreciated.

Comment: I believe the method within the static class must also be static as well. But I'm not positive.

Comment: You are correct, @DanielJackson. I updated the answer. Nice catch!